# Delete as many elements from the beginning of an array that match a value, until array reaches a specified size

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to modify an array by deleting values that match a unique ID, but then stop once the first 5 values of the array are valid (i.e. their IDs do not match the undesired ones). If the array has a count <= 5, then this suffices:

```
all_items = [{"id" => "id01"},{"id" => "id02"},{"id" => "id03"},{"id" => "id04"}]
exclude_ids = ["id01","id02"]
all_items.delete_if { |item| exclude_ids.include?(item["id"])}
```

and the desired output is `[{"id" => "id03"},{"id" => "id04"}]`.

But in the case where the total count of the array is >= 5, I want to delete *only* as many of the first items as necessary until the first 5 elements (`all_items[0..4]`) are all valid within the set criterion, and then stop iterating. If I were to do this:

```
all_items = [{"id" => "id01"},{"id" => "id02"},{"id" => "id03"},{"id" => "id04"},{"id" => "id05"},{"id" => "id06"},{"id" => "id07"},{"id" => "id08"},{"id" => "id09"},{"id" => "id10"}]
exclude_ids = ["id01","id02","id07"]
all_items.delete_if { |item| exclude_ids.include?(item["id"])}
return all_items[0..4]
```

I do get the desired output, `[{"id" => "id03"},{"id" => "id04"},{"id" => "id05"},{"id" => "id06"},{"id" => "id08"}]`. But I want the `delete_if` to completely stop once it reaches the point where `all_items[0..4]` already contains 5 valid elements. In this instance, I would want it to break after `{"id" => "id08"}`, and not even check the remaining values. (If, however, while the `delete_if` is running, the total count dips below 5, then it should continue iterating over all remaining elements, as it would fall into the category of the first piece of code I posted above, where the count <= 5.)

I know there is a `delete_if.with_index`, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate in this context, especially since the index would be shifting as items are deleted.

To summarize my question: is there a way to delete as many first items from an array as is required until `array[0..x]` is populated by desired values, and then stop checking/deleting any remaining items once that count of x is reached?

Comment: Sounds like `drop_while` .

Comment: `drop_while` will drop elements from the beginning. What if the first four and the sixth elements are valid and you need remove the fifth one to make a run of five?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it is not answered by the answer to which you awarded the greenie. See my comments on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
termination_threshold = 5
all_items = (1..20).to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
exclusions = [1,2,7]

all_items.reject! do |n|
  break if termination_threshold.zero?
  exclude = exclusions.include? n
  termination_threshold -= 1 if exclude
  exclude
end
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

all_items
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

The following could be used if only an array containing the first `termination_threshold` valid elements of `all_items` were desired:

```
all_items.each_with_object([]) do |e,arr|
  arr << e unless exclusions.include?(e)
  break arr if arr.size == termination_threshold
end
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you delete from the original object you end up with all the items that had not been deleted. So, I gues it is better to move just the desired items to a new object:

```
all_items.each_with_object([]) { |item, ary| ary << item if !exclude_ids.include?(item["id"]) and ary.size < 5 }

#=> [{"id"=>"id03"}, {"id"=>"id04"}, {"id"=>"id05"}, {"id"=>"id06"}, {"id"=>"id08"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerator::Lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to achieve what you want:

```
all_items = [{"id" => "id01"},{"id" => "id02"},{"id" => "id03"},{"id" => "id04"},{"id" => "id05"},{"id" => "id06"},{"id" => "id07"},{"id" => "id08"},{"id" => "id09"},{"id" => "id10"}]
exclude_ids = ["id01","id02","id07"]
all_items.lazy.reject {|item| exclude_ids.include?(item['id']) }.first(5)
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it does not modify `all_items`. Instead, it returns an array containing the first 5 elements of `all_items` that are not contained in `exclude_ids`. The OP was quite specific that elements of `all_items` were to be removed until the first 5 valid elements of `all_items` had been identified. The OP even mentioned the use of `delete_if` (aka `reject!`, not `reject`). I considered using a lazy enumerator, but there is no lazy `reject!`...

Comment: ...Suppose `all_times` has 1,000 elements and the first 3 fail the test and the next five pass. An array of elements at offsets 3-7 of `all_items` is returned and `all_items` is unchanged. What use is that? The OP wants to use `all_items` with certain elements removed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland based on return statement I deduced that the OP is just deleting elements because he wants to return the first five unrejected items, he doesn't care about the input. Moreover if deleting item was so important I assume deleting all the invalid items would have been priority instead of just rejecting to get the first five valid items.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sometimes refactoring doesn't simply mean rearranging the code for optimization or readability but identifying the underlying requirements and change the code to match requirements while optimizing and improving readability.

Comment: The last sentence of the OP's question unambiguous and is not the question you answered.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with you and understand that you have given a answer for exactly what OP was asking, but he did accept my answer so I would assume OP didn't mean that and was focusing on it simply because of the way he had implemented it already.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I chose the answer because as @rubish inferred, I was ultimately more concerned with the need to break out of the iteration once the first five unrejected items were found (which is why I didn't simply run a `delete_if` on the whole array in the first place). I was hung up on using `delete_if` only because I didn't know something like `.lazy.reject` existed, which ended up being exactly what I was looking for for my script (once I modified it so the output was stored in a new array, since, as @CarySwoveland points out, there is no lazy `reject!`).

Comment: I selected the answer that suited my personal needs, but for the sake of selecting an answer that technically responds to the exact question as I asked it at the time, I can change the accepted answer.

Comment: Given what you want, using a lazy enumerator is in my mind overkill. Moreover, lazy methods tend to be much slower than their non-lazy counterparts. I edited my answer to give a simple, straightforward calculation. In future, please ask how a desired end result could be obtained, rather than how a specific calculation could be done. Here that would be (sic) "How can I obtain an array containing the first 5 valid elements of `all_items` without enumerating the entire array, where an element is valid if...?.